# Magento Pagination in Ajax

Tags: ajax, magento, pagination

I have a problem in pagination.

It is creating a link like this: www.website.com/shoes.html&p=1

The correct would be like this: www.website.com/shoes.html?p=1

In place of "&" would have to be this "?". How do change it? Or how do disable the pagination in ajax?

I looked inside the page "pager.phtml" but is ok

```
    <?php foreach ($this->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
        <?php if ($this->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
            <li class="current"><?php echo $_page ?></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getPageUrl($_page) ?>"><?php echo $_page ?></a></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Thank you